# Android AVD freezes after launch from snapshot

Tags: android

I've been using AVD with snapshot for more than a year on Windows Vista. Recently my laptop stopped functioning, then I switched to Macbook Pro and installed the latest ADT (act-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140321, SDK Tools 22.6.2, SDK Platform-tools 19.0.1) on Mac OS X 10.9.2. Now I run into below problem with AVD snapshot feature:

1. Created first AVD with snapshot enabled, chose to launch from and save to snapshot. It worked fine.
2. Closed the AVD, then launched it again from snapshot (unchecked save to snapshot) to verify if the snapshot is proper. I was able to resume AVD from snapshot and perform normal task, then I closed it.
3. Repeated step #1 to create second AVD of different API level and configuration.
4. Relaunched second AVD to verify its snapshot, I was able to see the resumed screen of Android home screen, but the AVD is not responding - interacting with soft/physical buttons and on-screen icons gave no response, even waited after 30 minutes. LogCat didn't show any log. I closed this AVD and relaunched again, it didn't help.
5. Deleted the AVD, created a new one from fresh by repeating step #3 and #4. Ran into the same problem.
6. Performed step #2 to launch first AVD from snapshot again, oh no! the same problem seen at step #4 now happens to first AVD as well. Repeated step #5 for first AVD but problem persists.

Those AVDs work fine if I choose to use host GPU. Any clue?

Thanks for any input.